Headless Playwright Chromium Seatlh Not Rendering Full NextJS Webpage DOMS
I am running into this issue with websites such as palantir.com or rivian.com, which are both nextjs websites. I am building a web crawler to load any webpage and need the full DOM from each page. Unfortunately, most of the DOM is contained within a  tag and is stored as JSON.
The website is fully rendered if you navigate to it outside on your own.
Wondering if there is a solution that does require me to write a custom parser for nextjs webpages like these ones. Ideally, I would be able to render these webpages completely into the DOM as if I was navigating to it myself.
Python Script to see the  tag containing all the data not rendered into the DOM
import requests
response = requests.get("https://www.rivian.com/")
print(response.text)

My typescript implementation
import { chromium } from "playwright-extra";
import stealth from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth";
import randomUserAgent from "random-useragent";

chromium.use(stealth());
browser = await chromium.launch({
  headless: true,
  executablePath: process.env.PLAYWRIGHT_CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH,
});

context = await browser.newContext({
  userAgent: randomUserAgent.getRandom()
});

const page = await context.newPage();
const response = await page.goto("https://www.rivian.com/", {
  timeout: this.crawlRequest.timeout,
});
await page.waitForLoadState("networkidle", { timeout: 2500 });
var DOM = await page.content();
console.log(DOM);
await this.browser.close();

I tried to load a DOM of nextjs webpages from a Headless Playwright Chromium Seatlh instance in typescript. The DOM does not fully render. Majority of the DOM is in a script tag that no matter how long I wait does not load.

What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Do you want to scrape data, screenshot the page or perform some action? Other than screenshotting the whole page, you generally don't need to wait for the page to be "fully loaded". If screenshotting, generally wait for all images to load. These pages may also be blocking certain resources since you're headless, so you might try headful. So your goal has a big impact on how you define "loaded".

Generally, no need to use waitForLoadState--add waitUntil: to the goto options to avoid a race condition.
